# Django - Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very long await in my django rest framework project (up to 30 minutes) for a response from a websocket stream.
I am waiting for a user reply in the websocket (chat). I then want to save an instance of a model class to the database. However I get an error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` if the user is not responding within minutes. I can't change the logic since I need to monitor the websocket connection where the user is replying.

I tried to increase the connection duration by setting `CONN_MAX_AGE: 1800` in my *settings.py* but it seems that this doesn't do the trick.

Thanks

======== Update for @Nick ODell ========

Thank you! This is the response:

```
connect_timeout: 10

delayed_insert_timeout: 300

idle_readonly_transaction_timeout: 0

idle_transaction_timeout: 0

idle_write_transaction_timeout: 0

innodb_flush_log_at_timeout: 1

innodb_lock_wait_timeout: 50

innodb_rollback_on_timeout: OFF

interactive_timeout: 28800

lock_wait_timeout: 86400

net_read_timeout: 30

net_write_timeout: 60

rpl_semi_sync_master_timeout: 10000

rpl_semi_sync_slave_kill_conn_timeout: 5

slave_net_timeout: 60

thread_pool_idle_timeout: 60

wait_timeout: 120
```

Comment: Might be a timeout on the MySQL side. Can you log into MySQL, run the query `show variables like '%_timeout';` and paste the output into the question? See also the [MySQL manual's page on this error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html).

Comment: Instead of keeping the database connection open while waiting for the WebSocket response, you can use WebSocket to maintain the state. When you receive the user's response, you can then open a new database connection to save the data. Also instead of waiting for the user response in the same process that handles the database connection, you could delegate the task to a background job using a task queue such as Celery. This way, you can have a worker process that listens for the user's response and then saves the instance to the database independently of the request-response cycle.

Comment: Thank you @MBurak - Thats an intersting idea: So you would have a function like async def monitor_websocket(id):
# Code to keep the monitor alive and on new message calls this function:
async def handle_websocket_updates(message, id):
# Code to save the updates in the db
One thing that I dont understand: How can i include Celery here?